# Is there a way to compare output from find with diff in a bash shell?

Tags: bash

I'd like to take the output of find and be able to compare them with diff, to see if files are identical. For instance, let's say I find a few files with find:

```
find . -name '*.bar'

./desktop/filename.bar
./otherdirectory/filename2.bar
./otherotherdirectory/filename3.bar
```

I'd like to be able to do

```
diff ./desktop/filename.bar ./otherdirectory/filename2.bar
```

and

```
diff ./desktop/filename.bar ./otherotherdirectory/filename3.bar
```

and so on for all pairs of files found (to see at least if the files are identical) without having to write a command line for each pair.

The find -exec option won't work because it replaces {} with each result once at at time:

```
find . -name '*.bar' -exec diff {} \;
```

I also have tried piping the outputs of find to diff, but I can't get that to work, either (though I'm still a newbie and may be doing this wrong):

```
find . -name '*.bar' | diff
```

This may not be doable, but I'd rather not have to write a diff command for every pair of files I find with find.

Comment: It's not quite clear what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @user2888465 The title of your question does not really reflect what are really asking for, which seems to be a way to find identical files. Please consider changing the title (or specify what you are trying to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than attempting to `diff` all possible pairs of files in order to determine the duplicates, you could use `sha256sum` and compare the checksums instead:

```
find . -name '*.bar' -type f -exec sha256sum {} \;
```

Identical files would have the same checksum.  You could pipe the output of the above command to `sort` so that the result would be sorted by checksum:

```
find . -name '*.bar' -type f -exec sha256sum {} \; | sort
```

Comment: You should use `+` instead of `\;` so that `sha256sum` can handle more than one file at once. Also, if you pipe the sorted list to `uniq -w 64 --all-repeated=separate` you get a grouped list of only the duplicate files.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the solution worked for me as below

find . -name '*.bar' | xargs echo | xargs diff